# Expression Value Display

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display a value in an expression that i set through the value provider. I am a beginner at angular so pardon my childish mistakes. First two expressions with a filter are displaying correctly but the third expression which should display a "23" is displaying the whole expression written as it it "{{ vale}}".
The errors are

1. Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined.
2. Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myCont' is not a function, got undefined.

HTML:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div ng-app="myModule">
        <div>
            {{ 'World' | greet }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ 'Meow' | greet2 }}
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="myCont">
            {{ vale }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js:

```
 angular.module('myModule', [])

.config(function ($filterProvider, $provide) {
    $provide.value('a', '23');
    $filterProvider.register('greet', function () {
        return function (name) {
            return 'Hello, ' + name + '!';
        };
    });
    $filterProvider.register('greet2', function () {
        return function (name) {
            return 'Hello, ' + name + '!';
        }
    })

})

.controller('myCont', ['$scope', 'a', function ($scope, a) {
    $scope.vale = a;

}])
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: add quote to `a`  -> `.controller('myCont', ['$scope', 'a', function ($scope, a) {`

Comment: well it removes all the errors, and also the whole '{{ vale }}' that was displaying instead. But still doesnt show the value. Now only the first two expressions being evaluated

Comment: see http://plnkr.co/edit/vsjUgnDIHqJthkZNVCho?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, i figured from your fiddle what the problem was!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, i had used the wrong place to bootstrap my application, instead of starting on a div, i used ng-app on the html tag and it worked.